# Using Unchecked_Conversion to read in values and convert to a custom type

Tags: ada, unchecked-conversion

I'm quite confused on how `'Size` and `'Component_Size` work when reading input from a file and trying to use `Unchecked_Conversion`. I know that to sucsessfully use `Unchecked_Conversion` both the Source and the Target need to be the same `size`. I'm reading in input from a file like `000100000101001` and want to use Unchecked Conversion to put that into an array of Bits. However, the conversion always seems to fail because of them not being the same size or being too small.

```ada
    with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
    with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
    with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

    procedure main is
        type Bit is mod 2 with size => 1;
        type Bit_Array is array(Positive range <>) of Bit with pack;
        subtype Bit15 is Bit_Array(1 .. 15); //subtypes because can't use conversion on unconstrainted type
        subtype Bit11 is Bit_Array(1 .. 11);

        function StringA_to_Bit15 is
           new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(source => String, target => Bit15);


        begin
        while not end_of_file loop
            declare
                s: String := get_line; //holding first line of input
                len: constant Natural := (if s'length-3 = 15 
                                        then 15
                                        else 11); 
                i: Integer;
                ba: Bit_Array(1 .. len); //constrain a Bit_Array based on length of input
            begin
                ba := String_to_Bit15(s);
                new_line;
            end;
        end loop;
```

Here are my types, Bit which can only be 0 or 1 with `size` to 1 bit. Bit_Array is just an array of Bit's which is unconstrained because my input can either be 15-Bits long or 11-Bits long. My thought was to just read in the first line into a String and convert it into a Bit_Array. This doesn't work because String and every other primitive type aren't `Size => 1`. So Naturally I would want to create a new type to handle this which I tried in the form of, creating my own String type and setting the `size => 1` but Character requires 8-Bits. What data type would I need to create to read in a line of data and convert it such that it fits into a Bit_Array? I might be approaching this wrong but its very confusing for me. Any help or tips is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t use `Unchecked_Conversion` because, as you’ve found, a `Character` doesn’t correspond to a `Bit`. The 8-bit ASCII `Character` corresponding to `0` has a bit pattern corresponding to the decimal value 48, and `1` has value 49.

I think you’ll have to bite the bullet and loop through the input string. A simple function to do this, requiring that the input string consists only of `0`s and `1`s, might be

```
function To_Bit_Array (S : String) return Bit_Array is
   Input : constant String (1 .. S'Length) := S;
   Result : Bit_Array (1 .. S'Length);
begin
   for J in Input'Range loop
      Result (J) := (case Input (J) is
                        when '0' => 0,
                        when '1' => 1,
                        when others => raise Constraint_Error);
   end loop;
   return Result;
end To_Bit_Array;
```

(the point of the declaration of `Input` is to make sure that the index `J` is the same for both arrays; the first index of a `String` only has to be `Positive`, i.e. greater than 0).

Comment: This was my initial move aswell until I was told that the spec requires the use of Unchecked_Conversion. The reply I got when asking how, "What you need is a way to convert the strings that you've read into integer values then use Unchecked Conversion". Is there no way to achieve this by first converting the string of input to an integer type of some kind with `size => 1` because I know Integer's are `32` bit's but if i made my own type perhaps ? Thank you Simon

Comment: Yes this is a spec for a workshop I am taking on Ada, not exactly 'school' work but yes, I found this very odd. The example they wen't over worked when converting `x: Character := 'A;` into a, `type Bit_Array8 is Bit_Array(1 .. 8);` which conveniently matches the size in Bit's of a Character. This example is much to niche though to then ask us to read from input of 11 or 15 bits, which nothing naturally could fit in which is why I am very puzzled at this point on how to get the input into a Bit_array with UC

Comment: That is one crazy, non-Ada spec (I take it this is a class problem, not real-world? there must be better ways to teach UC, and UC is a bit of a code smell mostly). Anyway ... I suppose you could UC the Character into an 8-bit uint & subtract 48, but why not use `Character’Pos (C)`? In any case, you absolutely have to process the input string a character at a time; your `Bit11` will need an input string of length 88 bits! I can’t imagine a way of doing what is being asked, sorry. I’d be really interested to see what the official solution is.

Comment: You said in the question that the input lines were like `110100110001011`, but now you’re talking about `A`. I suppose that you could take `AB` as the input, convert to `Bit_Array (1 .. 16)`, and then take the low 11- or 15-bit slice. (a) what happens to the discarded bits? (b) what happens if you’re on a big-endian processor like a PowerPC, where the bits are numbered in the other direction?

Comment: yes, the input lines are how I mentioned in the question. The scenario I mentioned in my comment was the example we went over on how to use UC in the classroom, completely unrelated to the current problem posted here. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @FrédéricPraca, sorry, but syntax highlighting makes a colourized mess of anything with apostrophes in it. Also, the '3 backticks + language' trick really needs to have the leading 4 spaces that I used removed, or the whole thing goes annoyingly over to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Unchecked_Conversion however, if you are converting from say a modular integer type to a bit array. I generally avoid the use of Unchecked_Conversion unless as a last resort, but I can see the temptation to convert from an integer to a bit array type. However, I'd also consider whether to just use the modular integer, since it can be used for bitwise operations also. Using array syntax for accessing the bits is a nice feature, though. Even if I wanted to convert a modular integer to a bit array, I'd still recommend avoiding the use of Unchecked_Conversion, or pretty much Unchecked_ anything in Ada, when possible.
One reason is that Unchecked_Conversion will likely be less portable. 
Different compilers and different targets might store the bits in different orders, for example.

Another suggestion would be to use a packed array of Booleans, rather
than a packed array of bits. The storage in memory should look the same,
but I think you'll find it is more convenient to work with Booleans, rather than bits. It saves you from having to compare the values to 1 or 0.

So one way to convert your input strings to a modular integer is to use Ada.Text_IO.Modular_IO package.

```
type Short is mod 2**16;

package Short_IO is new Modular_IO (Num => Short);

type Bit_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Boolean
  with Component_Size => 1;
...

declare
     Input : constant String := Get_Line;
     Value : Short := 0;
     Last  : Positive;
     Bits_11 : Bit11;

     -- Instead of using Unchecked_Conversion, consider writing a 
     -- simple conversion function
     --
     function To_Bit11 (Value : Short) return Bit11 is
        ((for I in Bit11'Range => (Short(2**(I-1)) and Value) /= 0));

  begin

     --  Enclosing the input string with 2#{binary_string}#, 
     --  causes the number to be read in base 2, as a binary text
     --  string.
     Short_IO.Get (From  => "2#" & Input & "#",
                   Item  => Value,
                   Last  => Last);

     --  You could use unchecked conversion here to convert
     --  to the Bit array, but I'd recommend doing this
     --  without using unchecked features of the language
     --  e.g. using a simple loop

     for I in Bits_11'Range loop
        Bits_11 (I) := (Short(2**(I-1)) and Value) /= 0;
     end loop;

     --  or you can even try an Ada 2020 feature that already has
     --  been implemented in the latest community edition of GNAT.
     --  By assigning a new form of array aggregate to the 
     --  bit array object. You'd need to set the -gnatX compiler
     --  option to tell the compiler to use Ada extended 2020
     --  features. Many Ada 2020 features are not yet available to try
     --  out, but this one is available.

     Bits_11 :=
        (for I in Bits_11'Range => (Short (2**(I-1)) and Value) /= 0);

     -- or combine this into an expression function like above,
     -- then you have a function similar to the one you'd get using
     -- Unchecked_Conversion, except more portable, and one can
     -- examine the code to understand the implementation.

     Bits_11 := To_Bit11 (Value);
```